# Will Ubuntu 16.04 LTS have a 4.5.2 kernel update?

Tags: kernel

Will Ubuntu 16.04 LTS have an update for kernel version 4.5.2? I have an AMD GPU installed, and I heard this would fix AMD driver problems.

Answer (score 11):

Ubuntu 16.04 will never have a 4.5.2 kernel update.

Ubuntu does not update with mainline kernel versions.

Canonical Kernel Team backports bug fixes and some support of new hardware from upstream kernels to Ubuntu kernels.

Important fixes get into Ubuntu kernels 4.4.0-xx from 4.4, 4.5, etc mainline kernels.

You can see the source of Ubuntu 16.04 kernel [HERE](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git).

It is possible that the fix you need has been already backported.

Answer (score 10):

No, Ubuntu 16.04 will not have version 4.5.2 of the kernel. As you can see from a picture (taken from [16.04.x Ubuntu Kernel Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=16.04.x%20Ubuntu%20Kernel%20Support%20Schedule.svg)) of the kernel timeline for Ubuntu 16.04 below, the next version of the kernel will be a fork of version 4.8 of the mainline Linux kernel.

[image]

Comment: This is not 100% correct. It will not be `4.8.x`. It will be a fork of 4.8 ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 `x` was meant to denote the versioning on Ubuntu's side, but you are right ;). Let me fix it.

Comment: As you’re a reputation 21 user: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the “0” at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!